# Battlefield Bad Company 2 for MAC?

Tags: macos, battlefield-bad-company-2

Is there a working port of Bad Company 2 that works on MAC OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion.?
I got it on my steam account with the serial number etc, however the game only works on Windows.
I do not want to use bootcamp or parallels to run the game. I want to run it through the Mac OS directly.

Comment: Try using Bootcamp. It lets you run Windows on a MAC.

Comment: @art I should clarify that I do not want to use Bootcamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello fellow Mac user and BF:BC2 player! There aren't **easy way** to play Battlefield on Mac OS 10.8.

First try [using this](http://portingteam.com/files/file/4619-battlefield-bad-company-2/) but it should not work on 10.8. If you are afraid about legal issues check your country law about having a digital *safe* copy of product that you own.

If it don't work or don't want to be against law try with **CrossOver Mac software**. [Install Battlefield by Steam](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name/?app_id=7000) in Codeweavers so called "Bottle" and keep your fingers crossed. It have Silver medal so it should be playable.

[**Parallels Desktop**](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/gamers/titles/) should also be fine.

But I give you some random opinion that I can't agree more...

> Got it.  Played for 15 minutes.
>
> Deleted it.
>
> Low FPS, and didn't like it as an FPS. Graphics were bad.
>
> But thanks for trying.

And as you can see [on my stats page](http://bfbc2.statsverse.com/stats/pc/iber/) I know what I'm talking about.

**Install Bootcamp and own with 80+ FPS**

Comment: Would it work on VMWare or Parallels ?

Comment: Parallels will be OK. Check this (out of date but allways something) website - http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/gamers/titles/ IMHO VMWare will not handle it.

Comment: Thank you very much, im using bootcamp and I have a question, please check my other thread : http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97803/using-bootcamp-to-install-windows-and-play-steam-games-from-external-drive